# "VERR_SUPLIB_WORLD_WRITABLE" error when trying to installing OS in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I wanna install OS on VirtualBox,but when I wanna to install it,it will return errors:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Arch.
Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUPLIB_WORLD_WRITABLE).
Unknown error creating VM (VERR_SUPLIB_WORLD_WRITABLE).
```

Details:

```
Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
Console
Interface: 
IConsole {515e8e8d-f932-4d8e-9f32-79a52aead882}
```

I'm using ubuntu 11.04.

How should I solve it?

Comment: Please update your question to include the Host OS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be a problem related to the disk permissions settings https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=40525

From the above link

> Had the exact same problem& ran Repair Disc Permissions. After this tried again to open Virtual Box. Then received message including option to download & install Virtual Box Extension Pack. Went to http://www.virtualbox.com, downloaded Oracle VM Virtual Box 4.0.6 Extension Pack (ALL PLATFORMS), installed same and Virtual Box again opens and operates correctly.