# virtualbox - Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUPLIB_WORLD_WRITABLE)

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, chmod, virtualization

After I create a new Virtual Machine, when I start it, it shows following error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Milad.

Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUPLIB_WORLD_WRITABLE).
Result Code:    NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component:  Console
Interface:  IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}
```

My OS is ubuntu 14.04(64bit) Desktop with gnome.

I read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81071/verr-suplib-world-writable-error-when-trying-to-installing-os-in-virtualbox), but I can't understand what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same issue on ubuntu 14.04 (64bit) i just uninstalled it form */opt/Virtualbox*

by running the *./uninstall.sh* and installed the new version 4.3.18 and it ran perfect

Answer (score 1):

As alternative,
you didn't need to reinstall it, just change the file permission of VMMR0.r0.

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VMMR0.r0
```

That's work for me on VirtualBox 5.0.12 Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Hello answer of bagustris worked for me but with some changes 
i.e.

sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VMMR0.r0

Comment: Terrible idea to make it 777 if 755 works.

Comment: may be terrible for you but worked for me , thanks

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work: What I'm saying is that you should give someone a key to your front door if they want to come in, **not remove the lock entirely!**